# Unable to configure Gitlab lab with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I know it might have been asked but could not find any solution for this.
I am running `Jenkins` and `Gitlab` on different servers using docker. When i tried to add/configure the gitlab details in jenkins am

[image: getting below error]

Followed [this](https://dkaushik94.github.io/devops/2018/05/15/jenkins-gitlab/) link but not able to achieve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

What scopes does your api key have?
I usually use these: api, read_user, read_repository

Comment: API has everything including `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to test the api token manually via command line ( may be via trying to clone a repository ) to ensure the nothing wrong with that at the first place.